# What does 'WebDriverWait(driver, 20)' mean?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, constructor, webdriverwait

I am working with the following Selenium code:

```
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver

PATH= r"C:\Users\Hamid\Desktop\Selenium\chromedriver.exe"
driver=webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
click_button=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="L2AGLb"]/div').click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "q"))).send_keys("ONS data")
search=driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/center/input[1]').click()
```

I am not sure however what the breakdown for the following line of code is:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "q"))).send_keys("ONS data")
```

What does WebDriverWait mean? What does 20 refer to? What is meant by the EC element? Why does one need to wait? What does q refer to?

If I wanted to use this same code to work on a different item on the page, what would I typically change?

Comment: It means that the webdriver will wait for 20 secs, looking  the condition in `EC.`. In your case, it will wait for an element whose `name` attribute is "q" to become clickable. If it finds this element within 20 secs, then it will do the action at the end - `send_keys` - this will send the string "ONS data" as keyboard entry to th selected element on the web page

Comment: Thanks that is a very clear explanation. Out of curiosity, is there a way to click the element named 'q' and send keys without an expected condition (EC) or waiting 20s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the *API documentation* of [**WebDriverWait**](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) the constructor takes a WebDriver instance and timeout in seconds as arguments.

```
class selenium.webdriver.support.wait.WebDriverWait(driver, timeout, poll_frequency=0.5, ignored_exceptions=None)
```

```
where,
    driver: Instance of WebDriver (Ie, Firefox, Chrome or Remote)
    timeout: Number of seconds before timing out
    poll_frequency: sleep interval between calls By default, it is 0.5 second.
    ignored_exceptions: iterable structure of exception classes ignored during calls. By default, it contains NoSuchElementException only.
```

As an example, using the mandatory arguments:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "q")))
```

Using *lambda* expression:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda x: x.find_element(By.ID, "someId"))
```

Using all the arguments:

```
is_disappeared = WebDriverWait(driver, 30, 1, (ElementNotVisibleException)).until_not(lambda x: x.find_element(By.ID, "someId").is_displayed())
```