# Unable to access the button in Selenium Python using Xpath

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

Error Msg:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[text()="Cancel"]"}
```

I have tried with tagname as button too.

The HTML for this:

```
<form name="forgotPassword" id="forgotPassForm" action="https://login.salesforce.com/secur/forgotpassword.jsp"
              autocomplete="off" method="post" target="_top" novalidate="novalidate">
            <p class="username">To reset your password, enter your Salesforce username.</p>
            <input type="hidden" name="locale" value="in" />
            
            <div class="verifyform">
                <label for="un" class="label">Username</label>
                <input id="un" type="email" class="input wide mb12 mt8 username" onKeyPress="checkCaps(event)"
                       name="un" value="" autofocus />
                
                <input type="submit" name="continue" id="continue" class="button primary fiftyfifty right focus" value="Continue" />
                <input type="button" name="cancel" onclick="parent.location='/?locale=in'" class="secondary button fiftyfifty mb16"  value="Cancel" >
            </div>
            
                <input type="hidden" name="lqs" value="locale=in" />
            
            <div id='pwcaps' class='pwcaps' style='display:none'>Caps Lock is on. Please try to log in again and remember that passwords are case-sensitive.</div>
            <a class="hiddenlink" href="javascript:document.forgotPassword.submit();" id="continueReset">Continue</a>
            
                <p class="small">Video: <a href="http://salesforce.vidyard.com/watch/MxeeKTO3x5oMx4jNVWWX4w" id="video-link">Need Help Logging In?</a></p>
            
        </form>
```

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service("C:\\Users\\Dell\\Desktop\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe"))
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://login.salesforce.com/")
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#username').send_keys('Tac')
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.password').send_keys('PASSWRd')
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.password').clear()
driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, 'Forgot Your Password?').click()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Cancel"]').click()
```

Comment: I cannot see your image. Can you please update your question to reflect the community guidelines and make it easier for me to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element <kbd>Cancel</kbd> doesn't have a innerText rather the *`value`* attribute is set as ***Cancel***

```
<input type="button" name="cancel" onclick="parent.location='/'" class="secondary button fiftyfifty mb16" value="Cancel">
```

---

### Solution

To click element instead of [*presence_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57313803/7429447) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[value='Cancel']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@value='Cancel']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: I tried this clearly there's no more error but I am still unable to see the transitions between various steps. I understand this is working but for instance, my username field should have my input 'Tac' entered in the field>> then password>> clear the password>>clicking of Forgot my Password>> transition to the recover password page>>clicking of cancelling button and coming back to the login page but it is just landing on the login page and highlighting the username field and Pycharm console and no error.

Comment: Also, can you please explain why exactly we added WebDriverWait and 20 etc.

Comment: @Tac If you visit the embedded link each and every aspect used in this answer is described in details as an example [What does WebDriverWait(driver, 20) means?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71951054/7429447)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following code:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="forgotPassForm"]/div[1]/input[3]').click()
```

To get the basic XPath you can inspect element by right clicking on the web page and selecting 'Elements'. You can then right click the button and then 'Copy > Copy XPath'. This will allow you to get the very basics working before then refactoring and using a more robust piece of xcode.

See screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The element you are trying to access is `input` element NOT `button` element.

Use following `xpath` to identify the element.

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@name='cancel' and @value='Cancel']").click()
```

To handle dynamic element use `WebDriverWait()` and wait for element to be clickable.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='cancel' and @value='Cancel']"))).click()
```

You need to import below libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: So, I am learning through a Udemy course and he specified this way as a way apart from the way you have mentioned. Also, in his case , the course is few months old so the css html have few changes as in instead of input tag there was an anchor tag so his code worked for him with this syntax <driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='Cancel']")> and he didn't added WebDriverWait statement as well. Can you please help me why he was able to see all the transitions?